# php - return last 3 parts of string (url)

Tags: php, string

I need to get the last three parts of a string (url).  No need to pull the url from the browser as I already grab it from the database.

So, the string looks `like: www.mysite.com/uploads/09/03/myimage.png`

The part I'd like to extract from the string is `"09/03/myimage.png"`

Comment: try print_r($_SERVER) to find related values

Comment: The url is being pulled from the database and not from $_SERVER, so in this case I need to look through the string and grab the last part mentioned in question.

Comment: If its a valid url then you can simply use `parse_url` but as its not a valid url you need to use `regex` or `explode` function instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
 $url="www.mysite.com/uploads/09/03/myimage.png";
 $values=explode("/",$url); // this will split url string to array based on "/"char
 $length=sizeof($values); //calculated array length
 $lastthreeStringsCombined=$values[$length-3].'/'.$values[$length-2].'/'.$values[$length-1]; // formed new string by combining last 3 array elements
 echo $lastthreeStringsCombined;
?>
```

Comment: describe what you did and why, don't just dump some code.

Comment: @IntricatePixels The best solution is by mapek.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$lastThreeParts = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $url), -3, 3, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to pull out just the path part and ignore query parameters or hash values in the URL.

I would suggest using `parse_url()` (documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to pull out the path.

```
$url = 'www.mysite.com/uploads/09/03/myimage.png';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$output = array_slice($parts, -3, 3);
var_dump($output);
```

This will provide you with an array of the last 3 parts of the path and handles cases like query strings and hash values in the array, of course you will still need to do basic length validation to ensure this logic still holds.